# AngularJS optional ng-transclude

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-transclude

I have written a custom directive called 'news' in AngularJS 1.5.

It's layout is as follows:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="largeText shadow1" ng-transclude="heading"></div>
    <div class="mediumText shadow2" ng-transclude="content"></div>
</div>
```

The JavaScript file of this directive is as follows:

```
return {           
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: {
      'heading': 'heading',
      'content': 'content'
    },
    scope: {
        //Some parameters here
    },
    templateUrl: '/directives/news.html'
};
```

As you see, my news directive has two children, called heading and content fields. It can be used as follows:

```
<news>
    <heading>
        //Any content goes here
    </heading>
    <content>
        //Any content goes here
    </content>
</news>
```

So far, the directive works fine. I mean, as long as heading and content sections are filled with some content, the directive shows them as expected. However, I am trying to make these transclusion slots not mandatory. Whenever I use the directive as:

```
<news>
    <heading></heading>
</news>
```

AngularJS throws an error saying that I have not filled the content slot. Is it ever possible to make these slots optional?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

<s>I can't really find where it is in the actual documentation</s>, but based on an example I saw, I believe that you can use a `?` before the value to make the slot optional.

Example:

```
transclude: {
  'heading': 'heading',
  'content': '?content'
}
```

This comes from the example in angular docs at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude#multi-slot-transclusion. It is in the app.js.

You can also add a default for the cases where the slot is optional, by doing something like this:

```
<div class="largeText shadow1" ng-transclude="heading">Default stuff for the slot goes here</div>
```

**Edit**: actually I found it in the documentation. It says in this section https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#transclusion:

> If the element selector is prefixed with a `?` then that slot is optional.
>   For example, the transclude object `{ slotA: '?myCustomElement' }` maps `<my-custom-element>` elements to the `slotA` slot, which can be accessed via the `$transclude` function or via the `ngTransclude` directive.